# How to scrape a website with the socksify gem (proxy)

Tags: ruby, proxy, socks, tor, net-http

I am reading through the documentation of the [socksify gem](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/) on Rubyforge. I have installed the gem successfully, and I have run this documented code with success to test that my local implementation can replicate it:

```
require 'socksify/http'
uri = URI.parse('http://rubyforge.org/')
Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 9050).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  http.get(uri.path)
end
# => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

But how do I e.g. scrape `'http://google.com/'`, and get the html content? I wish to parse it with e.g. Nokogiri like this:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://google.com/))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 require 'socksify/http'
 http = Net::HTTP::SOCKSProxy(addr, port)
 html = http.get(URI('http://google.de'))
 html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

Comment: Thanks @mattes. But when I initiate with `http = Net::HTTP::SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 9050)`, and then run `html = http.get(URI('http://google.de'))`I get the response `301 Moved`.

Comment: That ist correct. `http://google.de` redirects to `http://www.google.de`. For more information, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Comment: Right you are. Thanks!

Comment: @mattes do you have any idea how to set user-agent using this method?